# Need an algorithm to match patterns

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, pattern-matching, data-science

[image: Pattern Examples]

My data is somewhat like the image above. I know the position along a horizontal axis of each data point. I also know the height of each data point. There is some number of people of interest in a reference pattern. (Shown in red). I want to be able to input a reference pattern and an example pattern and have an algorithm identify the people of interest in the example.

Height and position of people can vary. Thankfully, order is somewhat preserved because P1 can never pass P2. However, people can be missing from an example pattern. (Example 2). Also, extraneous people can appear in a pattern. (Example 1).

I would imagine there is a neural network or logistic regression model that I can implement to solve this. I can generate lots of artificial data to train with. I just need some help structuring it. Any suggestions are welcome. I am only moderately experienced in the field.

The current implementation I have for this uses maximum likelihood statistics. It is somewhat flawed and limited to examples where the number of people is greater than or equal to the reference.

Sorry for the low quality drawing.

Comment: what do you mean by 'people of interest'?

Comment: By 'people of interest,' I mean elements in the reference pattern that need to be identified in the example patterns. Not all elements in the reference pattern need to be identified in the example pattern.

Comment: Your matching rule is extremely unclear.  For example in example 2 why is nobody matched to P2?

Comment: The algorithm should detect that P2 is most likely missing. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but since it's not specifically about programming it's not suitable for SO. Try stats.stackexchange.com or maybe cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you would need neural network for this task. The most likely person [image] could be calculated for example like this

[image]

where f(x) is a deviation function of the height and h(x) of the position. (a and be can be used for weighting)

if this exceeded a threshold (you have to define one) the person is most likely not there

Comment: Imagine P1, P2, P3 have equal height and they are all spaced apart by 1 horizontal unit in the reference. Now imagine the pattern we are matching is nearly identical, but all elements have been shifted 1 horizontal unit to the right. With your function, I believe P1 would be identified as reference P2 and P2 would be identified as reference P3. P3 would be seen as extraneous and the function would classify P1 as missing. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.